# Collect telemetry from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to collect Android Studio usage and crash data, for my own company (ie not the standard telemetry sent to Google/JetBrains).

For example: I have projects that developers are reporting long load times, problems syncing, crashing etc in Android Studio but these issues don't appear in CI. I'd like to get local telemetry and report it, similar to how VSCode produces their telemetry.log file.

If this is not possible, are there any standin Gradle hooks I could use for common Android studio actions? For example the "sync" action - if I could tie this to a Gradle command maybe that's another way to get some data.